# How can I rotate a line of text each page refresh?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Right now, Reddit is down.  Every time you go to it, it displays a logo and below it a funny message.  Every time you refresh the page it displays a new message.

[image]

How could I write something simple that ~rotates~ (not random) a line of text on the page every refresh?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC but if there is a JavaScript solution to this problem that is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could write it:

For javascript, simply use the link posted by Andy White and replace the call to `Math.floor(7*Math.random())` to a get/set cookie value. You can find ready-to-use javascript functions to read and write cookies on google.

For asp.net mvc, the code won't differ a lot, you just have to look for functions to easily manipulate cookies as they are built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do it in javascript:

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/random_text_display_using_javascript_1.php3

Comment: Sorry, but I tried to specify in my post i'm ~not~ looking for random.  Thanks anyway though

Answer (score 0):

Load your message into an array or some sort of collection that is accessible by index.

Something like (i did not verify all syntax):

```
string getQuote(){
 //Load collection of lines
  ArrayList quotes = getQuotesData();
  int quoteCount = quotes.Count;

 // Set session or application variable to some number
  int counter;
  if( !Integer.parse( Session("counter"), counter ) ) { counter = 0; }
  if( counter > quoteCount ) { counter = 0; }

  return quotes[counter];
}
```

Also, I'm sure something similar is possible in javascript.