# How to Dynamically rotate the text in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

How to Dynamically rotate the text in HTML by using ASP.NET?

Comment: [How to ask a question on Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Venkatesh u wanted to rotate the text using javascript

Comment: @TimRogers am already searched. . if u knowing the answer means tell me pls

Comment: What do you mean by “Dynamically”? [What have you tried](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135049/encouraging-users-to-try-something-before-asking-write-me-code-that-questio)? Is this answers your question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/763056/55209

Comment: rotate the text by using the mouse. .lke dragging

Comment: i need by mouse we can able to rotate the text smoothly . .pls help me i searched. .

Comment: You can use jquery.rotate() function to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate the text in HTML using HTML5 and javascript as it is client side coding refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312752/how-to-make-the-text-write-in-counterclockwise-direction) as you can get some idea . Use canvas in HTML5 for rotating the text.